# Display a modal on incorrect user credentials

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two pages, `Login.php` and `LoginCheck.php`.I am validating for only correct and incorrect scenarios of the credentials in `LoginCheck.php`. I want to display a modal which is in `Login.php` on incorrect credentials. However,I don't know how to do that.

1. I tried alert, it shows the message in console only
2. I was thinking any how I could redirect the `else` of `LoginCheck.php` to the function of `Login.php` which is showing all other modals but don't know how to do that

Login.php

```
function openUserProfileModal ()
{
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

function validateLogin()
{
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var errorDescription = document.getElementById('errorDescription');
    var processing = document.getElementById('processingLogin');
    var Email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('Password').value;

    if(Email == "" && pass == "")
    {
        modal.style.display="block";
        errorDescription.innerHTML = "Please enter your email address and password";
    }
    else if (Email != "" && pass == "") 
    {
        modal.style.display="block";
        errorDescription.innerHTML = "Please enter your password";
    }
    else if (Email == "" && pass != "") 
    {
        modal.style.display="block";
        errorDescription.innerHTML = "Please enter your email address";
    }
    else if (Email == null && pass == null) 
    {
        modal.style.display="block";
        errorDescription.innerHTML = "Please enter your email address and password";
    }
    else
    {

        //processing.style.display = "block";

        // validation for correct and incorrect credentails
        ajax.sender_data_json_by_url_callback('LoginCheck.php', 
        {
            act: 'login',
            email: Email,                                       
            pass: pass
        });
        //this.check("LoginFornmDiv")
    }
```

LoginCheck.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_cache_expire();
session_start();
require_once("DBINTClass.php");
require_once("EncryptionClass.php");



if (isset($_REQUEST['act']) && $_REQUEST['act'] != '' && $_REQUEST['act'] != null && $_REQUEST['act'] == 'login') 
{

        $dd = new DBINT;

       $un = $_REQUEST['email'];
       $pw = $_REQUEST['pass'];
       $Encryptor = new Encryption();
       $ep = $Encryptor->EncryptPassword($pw);

       $id = (int)$dd->GetLogID($un,$ep);
       if ($id > 0)
       {
        $ltid = (int)$dd->GetLogTypeID($id);
        $d1h = $dd->GetHeaderDetails($id,$ltid);
        list($logintypename,$orgid,$orgtypeid,$orgname,$deptid,$deptname,$teamid,$personid,$persontypename,$firstname,$lastname) = explode(";",$d1h);

        $_SESSION['uid'] = $id; //user loginid
        $_SESSION['tpid'] = $ltid; //login type id: 1-Org Admin; 7-School Admin; 2-Department Admin; 3-Team Admin; 6-Teacher; 5-User; 6-CI Admin;
        $_SESSION['Company'] = $orgname;//org-school name
        $_SESSION['Person'] = $lastname.' '.$firstname;
        $_SESSION['PersonType'] = $logintypename;//login type name
        $_SESSION['orgid'] = $orgid;
        $_SESSION['orgtypeid'] = $orgtypeid;//1-organisation; 2-school
        $_SESSION['deptid'] = $deptid;
        $_SESSION['teamid'] = $teamid;
        //start Alex 23/12/2017 change calling functions
        $_SESSION['dept_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountDepartment($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number odf departments/classes
        $_SESSION['team_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountTeam($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number of teams/teachers
        $_SESSION['staff_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountStaff($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number of staff/student
        $_SESSION['language_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountLanguages($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number of language spoken
        $_SESSION['belief_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountWorldViews($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number of beliefs
        $_SESSION['country_cnt'] = $dd->GetHeaderCountCountries($ltid,$orgid,$deptid,$teamid);//number of countries
        //end Alex 23/12/2017 old functions ????
        $_SESSION['lhd'] = $d1h;
        //keyfacts guages calculations
        $ril = $dd->RICalculation($orgid,$deptid,$teamid,$ltid);
        list($ldli,$dli,$ldei,$dei,$ldwi,$dwi,$lrii,$rii) = explode(";",$ril);
        $_SESSION['de'] = $dei;
        $_SESSION['dl'] = $dli;
        $_SESSION['dw'] = $dwi;
        $_SESSION['ri'] = $rii;
        $_SESSION['lde'] = $ldei;
        $_SESSION['ldl'] = $ldli;
        $_SESSION['ldw'] = $ldwi;
        $_SESSION['lri'] = $lrii;
        $result = array("act" => "location", "Result" => "PanelAdmin.php");
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        else
        {

            //Show modal in here somehow
        }
}
?>
```

Please help

Comment: `LoginCheck.php` should send back an error (as json), in your ajax (not shown here) you can then check if you got an error and do something like `modal.style.display='modal';` - since we don't know your ajax function nor your modal it's hard to answer..

Comment: sidenote: avoiding variable/index names such as 'ldli' and 'ldii' will avoid future headache...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. I learnt AJAX first and then use it, such as, AJAX call. Sent the user from Login.php to LoginCheck.php and displayed the error in `else` statement using AJAX, if that makes sense.